# Inserting Category programmatically

Tags: categories, filters, terms

I am wondering how should i insert the category programmatically and it   should insert only 1 time after the theme is activated.

I know up to here.

```
function example_insert_category() {
    wp_insert_term(
        'Science',
        'category',
        array(
          'description' => 'This is an Science category.',
          'slug'        => 'science'
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'example_insert_category' );
```

i don't know how to insert children etc. I want to insert category structured like this:

```
Science
--Grade 11
----Science
----Management
----Humanities
--Grade 12
----Science
----Management
----Humanities

MIT
--Grade 15
----Science
----Management
----Humanities
--Grade 16
----Science
----Management
----Humanities
```

Is it possible to do programmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the [return value of `wp_insert_term`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term#Return_Values) and use it to build your structure. A successful return value will be an array with a `term_id` key that you can pass into `wp_insert_term`'s `$args` array as `parent`.

```
$parent = wp_insert_term('Science', 'category'); // I'll leave out `$args` here
if (is_wp_error($parent)) {
  // insert didn't work! return from your function or error or whatever
  return;
}

// grade 11 category has "Sience" as its parent
$grade11 = wp_insert_term('Grade 11', 'category', ['parent' => $parent['term_id']]);
if (is_wp_error($grade11)) {
  // same as above, something went wrong
  return;
}

// Management has the parent "Grade 11"
wp_insert_term('Management', 'category', ['parent' => $grade11['term_id']]);
```

As far as only inserting one time, you can hook into [`after_switch_theme`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_switch_theme) and do your stuff. You'll probably want to look up your term first to make sure it hasn't been inserted, or set an option with the inserted term ID on success.

```
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'wpse206511_switch');
function wpse206511_switch()
{
    if (get_option('wpse206511_term_id')) {
        // already done, bail
        return;
    }

    // category insert code from above

    // set the term ID in an option that you can check later
    // if/when the theme gets activated/deactivated again
    add_option('wpse206511_term_id', $parent['term_id']);
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks. But suppose i have more category like Science should i repeat the code from begining?

Comment: Yep. You you just need to walk down the tree for each category. Start with the toplevel parent, insert next level parents, insert the child categories.

Comment: yea and in second part of code should i manually insert category id in option ?

Comment: If you have more than one category you can track each ID or just track a boolean value to mark that you inserted things. `add_option('wpse206511_inserted_terms', true)` for instance. Your call.

Comment: yes using your idea i did it . And successfully got inserted. But want to know is it good if we have large number of categories. I have even created a paste bin . Is it good to do like this? http://pastebin.com/rJ1QFgxF

Comment: It should be fine. The only way you'll know if it's too many or its an issue is if your server starts to underperform when it's under load. Until then, it's not a problem worth worrying about.